# Creating shapefiles using java?

Tags: qgis, java

I have a running java service which gives me a count corresponding to every 5-digit zip code in Newyork state. Now i want to feed this input to QGIS programatically so that the color of every polygon (corresponding a zip code) is set according to count associated with it (which is given by java code).

I already have the shapefile corresponding the zip code boundaries in NY state. So basically , i do not want to right click and set the color , i want java to do it by editing the shapefile.

Comment: You can not "really" specify a color in a data file. You could write a color string (like #A1A1A1) to a column and prepare a QGIS style that uses that as data-defined color. But I doubt that this would be a satisfactory solution for you?

You can load and save shapefiles with OpenJUMP's API in Java.